# flutter TimeOfDay to json

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on an alarm clock type application where I need to save time for different days of week.

Something like this:

```
[
  {
    'day': 'Sunday',
    'time': '11.00 A.M' --> on Sunday the alarm will fire at 11.00 A.M
  }
  {
    'day': 'Monday',
    'time': '1.00 A.M' --> on Monday the alarm will fire at 1.00 A.M
  }
]
```

This is the model I've written:

```
class ReminderModel {
  String? dayName;
  TimeOfDay? startTime;
  TimeOfDay? endTime;
  TimeOfDay? frequency;
  TimeOfDay? breakDuration;
  bool? isPending;

  ReminderModel({
    this.dayName,
    this.startTime,
    ...
  });
  factory ReminderModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ReminderModel(
        dayName: json["dayName"],
        startTime: json["startTime"],
        ...
      );
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "dayName": dayName!,
        "startTime": startTime!.toString(),
        ...
      };
}
```

I'm using Hive for local db use. Saving is no issue(I guess `toString()` is correct). But during splash screen I'm loading all the data and this is the error I get:

```
Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Invalid date format
```

Since I only need the `Time` I thought using `TimeOfDay()` is enough. What am I doing wrong here?

**N.B:**I've not been clear which line causes the error. And honestly my best guess is it't the `fromJson()` method. I'm sure I'm not parsing it right. That's why when the app loads the data is not getting loaded right

Comment: What line of code throws the error? I know with Hive lots of formats aren't supported and have to be saved as Strings which it looks like you did. I'm going to guess when re-creating the Date/Time object you need to properly parse the data/string you are passing in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are passing wrong keys during parse the data.
2. Time is coming in string format, you can to convert it to TimeOfDay in fromJson. And one more thing is that flutter doesn't support HH.MM format. Please  use HH:MM format

Comment: Since it's happening after I launch the app. So I'm guessing the `fromJson()` method. Because I'm saving the alarm data in json in HiveDB. As toJson() is working then `from Json()` is the problematic one

Comment: Can you provide an example or code for the suggestion you provided?

Comment: Yes sure i'll provide

Answer (score 0):

To convert `TimeOfDay` to JSON, you're essentially asking how to serialize and restore a `TimeOfDay` object. There are a couple options:

### DateTime

Use an intermediary `DateTime` object to store the hours and minutes from `TimeOfDay`. You can use whatever year, month, and day you like:

```dart
final time = TimeOfDay(hour: 14, minute: 30);
final dateTime = DateTime(
  DateTime.now().year,  // whatever
  DateTime.now().month, // whatever
  DateTime.now().day,   // whatever
  time.hour,
  time.minute,
);
final serialized = dateTime.toIso8601String();
// 2023-08-11T14:30:00.000
```

Then restore the `TimeOfDay` like so:

```dart
final serialized = '2023-08-11T14:30:00.000';
final dateTime = DateTime.parse(serialized);
final time = TimeOfDay.fromDateTime(dateTime);
// TimeOfDay(14:30)
```

### Custom Serialization

`TimeOfDay` is mostly just a wrapper around hours and minutes. So you could just save those two numbers in some way.

One possibility would be like so:

```dart
final time = TimeOfDay(hour: 14, minute: 30);
final serialized = '${time.hour}:${time.minute}';
// 14:30

final parts = serialized.split(':');
final hour = int.parse(parts[0]);
final minute = int.parse(parts[1]);
final deserialized = TimeOfDay(hour: hour, minute: minute);
// TimeOfDay(14:30)
```